# Debug Cython with python-dbg fails with undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4_64

Tags: debugging, cython, dbg

I am trying to debug a small cython project following the [instructions](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/debugging.html) from the official Cython page. but the command:

`python-dbg setup.py build_ext --inplace`

fails with the error below. I have seen responses to a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587136/numpy-fails-with-python-dbg-undefined-symbol-py-initmodule4-64) but I don't think it applies for me as I am running Cython installed via apt-get. Any help would be much appreciated.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 4, in 
    from Cython.Build import cythonize

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/**init**.py", line 1, in  from Dependencies import cythonize

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 51, in  from Cython.Compiler.Main import Context, CompilationOptions, default_options

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 17, in  from Scanning import PyrexScanner, FileSourceDescriptor
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4_64
[35101 refs]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
In this article the cause of it is explained:

> The problem [..] is the python-dbg binary however is incompatible with
>   modules not compiled with them

http://hustoknow.blogspot.de/2013/06/why-your-python-program-cant-start-when.html

My solution was to uninstall cython (which was installed via pip), clone the cython github repo and manually install it with python-dbg:

```
git clone git@github.com:cython/cython.git
cd cython
sudo python-dbg setup.py  install
```

Afterwards I was able to `python-dbg setup.py build_ext --inplace` in my own code.

Comment: According to this you should now use `python setup.py install` https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/INSTALL.txt